# Infinite Rays in Trees

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I was wondering if it was possible to have an infinite ray in a finite tree? This is impossible merely from the fact that an infinite ray goes through infinite vertices, contradicting the finiteness of the tree right?

Is it fine if I just stated this as an obvious lemma?

Thanks.

Comment: How is a ray in a tree defined? You may have to use the fact that a tree has no cycles.

Comment: An infinite path where for every vertex in the path, two of its adjacent vertices are also in the path

Comment: @guy Are you sure of that definition? I would have expected a "ray" to be a path that was infinite in just one direction, i.e., a connected graph with one vertex of degree $1$ and all other vertices having degree $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That a finite tree cannot contain an infinite path doesn’t even rate as a lemma. It is at most a passing remark that follows immediately from the definitions of *finite*, *infinite*, *tree*, and *path*.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.